# wxpython transfer argument

Tags: wxpython, args

There are two scripts, one calling another with arguments (*args) and the other get called and display a form, displaying a form works fine but no arguments transfered from calling script.  I tried to run the called script via command line and got the same result.  Here the snippet of both scripts
python 2.7.14   wxPython3.0.2.0-py27 win 10

```
sy0000.py  calling  sy0001.py

def CallPGM( self, event ):
    lstParms = ['python', 'sy0001.py']
    dctParms = {"pgm_version_id": "ver0000"}
    lstArgs = ['ver0000', 'noby']
    #os.system("python sy0001.py " + "ver0000")    # works but args not transfered
    strParms = "python sy0001.py " + "ver0000"
    os.system(strParms)  # works but args not transfered
    #subprocess.Popen(lstParms + lstArgs)    # works but args not transfered
    #subprocess.Popen('python', 'sy0001.py', 'abcd', 'ver0000', 'noby')  # buffer size error
    #subprocess.Popen(['python', 'sy0001.py', 'abcd', 'ver0000', 'noby'])  # works but args not transfered
    subprocess.call(lstParms + lstArgs)                                   # works but args not transfered
    #subprocess.call(['python', 'sy0001.py', 'abcd', 'ver0000', 'noby'])  # works but args not transfered
    #subprocess.call('python', 'sy0001.py', 'abcd', 'ver0000', 'noby')  buffer size error
    self.Destroy()


sy0001.py called by  sy0000.py

import wx 
class MyFrame( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parm1, *args, **kargs ): 
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parm1, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"BioInformatics", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 1200,700 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL, *args, **kargs )

        print "sy0001 init "
        print args
        print "==ok="
        print kargs
        print "==2ok="
        print parm1
        print "==parm1ok="



    app = wx.App(False) 
    frame = MyFrame(None) 
    frame.Show(True) 
    #start the applications 
    app.MainLoop()
```

I have tested several methods of calling, but the results are the same as follow:
    sy0001 init
    ()
    ==ok==
    {}
    ==2ok==
    None
    ==parm1ok=

I am using win 10 python2.7 wxpython3.0 and those versions must be remained.
Appreciated if somebody points out what I am doing wrong.  Or win 10 is causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling the script `within` python but passing control to your operating system, so parameters are only available from `sys.argv`.
The concept of keyword arguments goes out the door at the same time.
You have to access the arguments passed on the command line, ignoring parameter 0 which will be the script name.

```
import wx
import sys
my_args = sys.argv

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="BioInformatics", size=(400,300))
        print ("sy0001 init ")
        print (args)
        print ("==ok=")
        print (kwds)
        print ("==2ok=")
        #Convert args to a list to print out
        largs = [elem for i in args for elem in i]
        for item in largs:
            print (item)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyFrame(None, my_args[1:])
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Command:

```
python sy0001.py 123 j=42 66
```

Output:

```
sy0001 init 
(['123', 'j=42', '66'],)
==ok=
{}
==2ok=
123
j=42
66
```

Comment: @noby As you are new here, there is a Grey Tick mark next to the answer and up and down arrows above it. If an answer answers your question click the Grey Tick to Accept the answer. If the answer didn't answer the question but was helpful click the up arrow to indictate that it was useful. If, on the other hand, the answer was total tosh, click the down arrow, to indicate that it was not helpful at all.

Comment: I got your message about responding whether the answer helped or not, but I don't know where the Grey Tick mark is located.  If I knew where it was, I would say the answer perfectly solved my problem.

Comment: @noby Hi, to the left of the answer you will see an Up ▲ sign a 0 and a down ▼ sign. These are used to up and down vote an answer. Below these is a greyed out Tick ✔ sign. This is used to accept an answer; if you click it, it will turn green.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass arguments to a script like that, they are stored in `sys.argv`.

Try replacing:

```
frame = MyFrame(None)
```

with

```
import sys
frame = MyFrame(None, *sys.argv)
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise.  I changed to MyFram(None, **sys.argv) and got an error saying "type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not list", so I changed to MyFrame(None, sys.argv).  I got another error saying "Argument given by name ('id') and position (2)".  I don't understand the meaning of error.  Noby

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `*sys.argv` instead of `**sys.argv`.